# What's the TDD correct way of mocking server interaction i my case?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd, bdd, rspec-rails

I know this is not a true or false question, but here is what I am trying to solve. I am working on a rails web app that interacts with a [SoftEther VPN Server](https://www.softether.org/).
SoftEther does not provide an API but it has a command line administration tool (vpncmd) which can handle all the tasks I need to do. At first I tried to rely on rake tasks and direct calls to the command line tool but when I tried to write some tests for them I realized it was not the best option.
Now I am writing a [wrapper class](https://github.com/bananabr/RSRS/blob/master/app/lib/soft_ether.rb) which I can properly test. The problem I still do not know how to handle regards server calls.
Some methods like "create_user!" should be verified by confirming that a new user was created in the server, for this to possible, I can currently running a docker container that runs an actual instance of the SoftEther VPN Server. A new container is created at the beginning of my rspec file inside a before_all hook and destroyed at the end in an after_all hook.
Is my solution bad in any way? If yes, what would be the TDD way of doing it right?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

There are several options that are open to you.  First off I just want to mention that you can test your rake tasks without a wrapper.  Here is a good write up on that:  https://robots.thoughtbot.com/test-rake-tasks-like-a-boss.

Now to answer your question.  Personally I would [mock or stub](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-14/docs/message-expectations) the response to the methods that make calls to external services.  To do this you simply record a successful call/response to your api and you stub it out by using:

```
allow_any_instance_of(Object).to receive(:foo).and_return(:return_value)
```

Where Object is your Class, Foo is your method and :return_value is the return_value.

Another option you have that May be easier in the short term is to use the [VCR gem](https://github.com/vcr/vcr).  VCR basically records your requests and the responses from the service if there is no cassette that exists(A cassette is basically a recorded response).  If a cassette exists, VCR will prevent your app from making the external call and will simply play back the response on the previously recorded cassette.  I like VCR a lot but there is a learning curve for it, and if you have never used it before it can bring its fair share of headaches.  If you are still confused feel free to post some example code that you are having trouble with and I will do my best to get you on your way.